# Error while doing Geocoding using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid value for property <address>:
```

Following is the code that does the geocoding:

```
function codeAddress(zipcode){
var address = zipcode;
alert("Address is: " +address);
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, 
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
}
```

The function takes a parameter 'zipcode' from the following code:

```
<input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress(<%=resultset.getString(3)%>)">
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: What is resultset.getString(3) ?

Comment: for more information see the answer given by me at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679118/how-to-find-lat-long-of-a-given-area-using-pin-code/8710888#8710888

Comment: @amit resultset.getString(3) means that i am getting the value of zipcode from a SQL Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the rendered `onclick="codeAddress(<%=resultset.getString(3)%>)"` actually has a string being passed to `codeAddress()`. You may have to add single quotes inside of that: `onclick="codeAddress('<%=resultset.getString(3)%>')"`

Comment: It is getting passed. That is what i am checking in the third line of function codeAddress.

Comment: I don't mean "is it getting passed" but "is it a string?". You might be getting this error because address is a number, not a *javascript* string.

Comment: thanks you very much. I added single quotes and it is working as i wanted. And yeah, thank you for giving me above suggestion. Learned new thing.